# Geth debug_traceCall logs parsing

Tags: go-ethereum, trace

So I have a geth client with debug api enabled, I use it with debug_traceCall in order to trace a call. I want to parse generated event logs from the traceCall (without using custom js parser in the call)

I receive something like this

```
{
    pc: 7042,
    op: 'LOG3',
    gas: 46090390,
    gasCost: 1756,
    depth: 6,
    stack: [
      .....
      '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
      '0x20',
      '0x80'
    ],
    refund: 29500
  },
```

For exemple here I can see the topics 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef

How can I retrieve the address associated with this log? I can't find it in the "stack" array.